# glGenVertexArrays Not Initializing VAO array

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc

I'm trying to learn a newer version of OpenGL using MFC and I'm following the red book.

I've done a quick test with a SDI project where:

1. In my CView inherited class I've created my contest and started glew.
2. Added a class called "entity" where I wrote down part of the first example, in particular the initialization of vertexes and buffers.
3. In OnDraw of my CView I call entity.Draw() and had some results.

Now, I've moved the CView inherited class (COGLView) and the entity in a DLL, made a test project, where my view inherit from COGLView and I've an object of my entity.
I've digged into my entity constructor to check some stuff and I've noticed that:

```
glGenVertexArrays( NumVAOs, m_vVAOs );
```

does nothing to m_vVAOs, while in the previous test project (before moving stuff into the dll) sets the value m_vVAOs[0] to 1.
Is this regular or I'm doing something wrong?
Also, feel free to ask me portions of code which might be useful.

ADDENDUM: Every gl* function exit with code 0... (glCreateProgram, glCreateShader...)

Comment: The only thing moving this to a DLL _might_ change has to do with thread local storage. Some frameworks store the currently active render context in TLS and do not play well with DLLs - but if this were the case, no GL command would have any affect when called from your DLL. Is it just the call to `glGenVertexArrays (...)` that is behaving strangely?

Comment: Well, I've tried to draw some lines in the old way (glBegin....) into the Draw function and everything went fine. I have pratically no idea yet of what's going on with the other functions. m_vVAOs remains uninitialized, while the shader do not get compiled (but this might be another error unrelated to this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As guessed it was my fault: I was doing operations **BEFORE** setting the OpenGL context.